# Is there any HTML5 benchmarks, especially large ones?

Tags: html, html-parsing, benchmarking

I want to test an HTML parser's performance. It is written in Java. However, the parsing time for a regular HTML file is too small to measure, like 5 milliseconds.

So I am looking for a large enough HTML as our benchmarks. If you know any websites or webpages are really large, or you know any existing benchmark suites of HTML, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing HTML is lightning quick in **every** situation - a big HTML document doesn't take a long time to render because of the HTML parsing process, but because of the logic involved in the layout engine (no trivial task!).

For example, I have a 2MB HTML file that's a dump of an internal tool of ours. Firefox and IE both render it instantly because it has a very simple stylesheet, but I also have a 30KB HTML file that uses a load of interesting layout techniques (and plenty of `box-shadow`s) that takes about 200ms to render.

If you have a huge HTML file that you want to display more quickly then there are different approaches (such as splitting the page up, paging data, or loading on-demand with Ajax techniques).